# Outlook 2007 panes keep moving when changing resolution

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, resolution

This problem is really bugging one of our users ever since he got a larger monitor. Now that the monitor has a different resolution than his laptop, every time he unplugs it to go home, the three Outlook panes get all jumbled up. The navigation is huge, the list is shoved over, and the reading pane is almost smushed out of existence, the the opposite when he comes back in and the reading pane fills the screen. He's sick of adjusting it every day. He always runs it maximized, for maximum reading area. Keeping the application within a 1024x768 window wouldn't really be an option for him.

Is there any way built into Outlook to automatically adjust pane sizes when the resolution changes? If not, is there a third-party app that can help, or a way to script the changes into the registry somehow? (I can do running the script whenever the screen state changes.)

If this is fixed in 2010 I might be able to convince the other admin that this is a good enough reason to allow it (which will require a new beta version of our archiving software).

Answer (score 0):

A way around this could be to use two different user accounts for work and home.  In each account, Outlook could still be connected to the same mail accounts and the user folders, like Documents and Desktop, could be mapped to the same folders.  All that would be different between the user accounts would be program settings.

Another possibility could be to use different Outlook profiles, but I am not sure if this would work.  It may be worth checking out, as this would be easier and have less drawbacks.

Comment: That would be pretty ugly, since his Exchange account is about 20GB (and regularly butts up against the Outlook limit), all cached offline. I'll check it out though, maybe one account can be set uncached if the head admin allows it.

Comment: @SilverbackNet: It may be possible to share the same .ost file between accounts, but I am not curious enough to test myself.  Having both accounts logged on at the same time would lead to disaster though, I would imagine.